# Flex / AIR / AS3 XML newline problem

Tags: xml, apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, air

i have an xml i load within my air app which looks like this:

```
<chapter title="hello" nr="111" src="">
<page>
<text>To adjust <br/><br/>. . .</text>
<text>To adjust <br/><br/>. . .</text>
</page>
</chapter>
```

when i trace or debug what is between the text element ... i get:

```
To adjust <br/>
<br/>
. . .";
```

Why do i get those newlines, or even better... how do i get rid of them?
(the full xml is a bit more complicated but i load the xml-file in a xmllist-component and navigate the structure until i get the correct value)

The page-element is loaded in a XMLList-component and with a for-loop I read the data from the text-elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want [lineEnding](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html#lineEnding)

Comment: I have found a (different) solution but this works as well. My solution was to work with a load of replace functions on the string between the text-element

Answer (score 1):

Option 1 - USE `<![CDATA[  ]]>`

```
<chapter title="hello" nr="111" src="">
  <page>
    <text><![CDATA[To adjust <br/><br/>. . .  ]]></text>
    <text><![CDATA[To adjust <br/><br/>. . .  ]]></text>
  </page>
</chapter>
```

Option 2 - use `&lt;` and `&gt;` for  < and  >

Then `<br/> = &lt;b/&gt;`

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's

```
XML.prettyPrinting = false;
```

see [prevent pretty printting - wonderfl build flash online](http://wonderfl.net/c/4DBW)

Answer (score 0):

When you load the xml, set the ignoreWhitespace property to true.

```
XML.ignoreWhitespace = true;
```